# Is it okay to write dispose method for a class?

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a class (called Employee. non static) defined in a class library. I am instantiating that class in another project and calling some methods.

Is it okay to write a Dispose method in that class? The reason I wanted to write custom dispose method because I am calling a webservice inside Employee class.

```
public class Employee
{

    SoapSample company = new SoapSample();

    public Employee()
    {
        company.UserCredentials.UserName = "";
        company.UserCredentials.Password = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't just implement the IDisposable interface?

Comment: I think he knows about the IDisposable interface. This is what he means when he asks if he should write a Dispose method. The real question is if this object should implement IDisposable and it is a fair question.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it would hurt to implement IDisposable, but I do question whether it's actually necessary.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but it does hurt to implement IDisposable when it is not needed. IDisposable is a contract that says Dispose() should be called. If you implement IDisposable on something that does not need it you are putting a burden on the client developer to wrap everything in usings or call Dispose manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just implement the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface

```
public class Employee : IDisposable
{

    SoapSample company = new SoapSample();

    public Employee()
    {
        company.UserCredentials.UserName = "";
        company.UserCredentials.Password = "";
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         //TODO:put your cleanup code here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The web service client should be stateless anyway, I'd expect. What *unmanaged* resources would you want to dispose? Sounds like you don't need it.

EDIT: It feels like an odd design for an `Employee` type to have a reference to a soap client to start with, to be honest. Are you sure this is an appropriate design?

Comment: Who will call the dispose method on the web service client which (I assume) holds an unmanaged resource??

Comment: @Stilgar: It's not clear to me what unmanaged resources it would be holding, to be honest.

Comment: Me either but it does implement IDisposable (has a public Close method) so I assume there are in fact unmanaged resources involved. Otherwise why does the client implement IDisposable?

Comment: @Stilgar: Sometimes that's for remoting purposes... I'd need to take a closer look, basically.

Comment: Sure but as client code Employee needs to call Dispose. It is kind of a contract. This is why in my answer I advise that he implements disposable if he keeps the client open in some way and NOT implement it if he can just close it in the same method call.

Comment: @Stilgar: It depends on the implementation. There are times when it really *is* necessary, and times when it isn't. For example, I doubt that many people call `Dispose` on a `DataTable`. *Usually*, I agree. But to be honest, I strongly suspect that the `Employee` class simply shouldn't have this member.

Comment: SoapSample is WCF call and in the dispose method I wanted to close it. `code` public void Dispose() {

            if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                client.Abort();
            else
                client.Close();        
        } `code`

Comment: @CoolArchTek: Well, it's the WCF *client* presumably. It's not a call in itself. The question is whether you actually *need* to close it (and if so, why)... and more importantly than that, whether an `Employee` entity should have something like that in the first place. (It's not the sort of design I'd normally have myself.)

Answer (score 2):

A class `Foo` should generally implement IDisposable in two cases:

1. At least some instances of `Foo` will know of some task that should happen sometime, but which no other object is likely to do in timely fashion, and they will know that the task in question may be safely performed once they themselves are no longer needed.

   At least some classes derived from `Foo` are apt to meet the above criteria, and have their last useful references held by code which expects to work with them as type `Foo`, rather than a more derived type.

Something like `Bitmap` fits the first category, since when it is created it asks Windows to give it a GDI handle for its exclusive use, meaning: (1) Something needs to tell Windows when that handle is no longer needed; (2) If the Bitmap doesn't do it, nothing else will; (3) Once the `Bitmap` is no longer needed, the GDI handle may be safely deleted.

Something like `Stream` fits the second category.  The base class isn't aware of any particular things that will need to be done before an instance can be safely abandoned, but many derived classes will have such requirements.  Further, there are many cases in which an object may create a `Stream` for purposes of handing it off to some other object, and then have no further use for itself.  The object creating the `Stream` shouldn't have to care about when the second object gets done with the stream, and the object receiving the `Stream` shouldn't have to worry about whether it's a type that actually requires cleanup or not.  Instead, the simplest pattern is for the creator of the `Stream` to hand it over in a method that makes clear the recipient is expected to clean it up, and for the recipient to call `Dispose` without worrying about whether the method actually does anything in the particular type it was given.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. But you should do so by inheriting and implementing the `IDispose` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Just implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

Your employee class should implement the `IDisposable` interface. Check out the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes...  make that class implement `IDisposable`

```
public class Employee : IDisposable
{
        public void Dispose()
        {..}
}
```

But it will have a meaning only if that class uses an unmanaged resources.

When to use `Dispose` ? :

> Use this method to close or release unmanaged resources such as files, streams, and handles held by an instance of the class that implements this interface. By convention, this method is used for all tasks associated with freeing resources held by an object, or preparing an object for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to keep the client object for the lifetime of the object? If not just dispose of the client inside the method you are calling it and if yes implement a disposable pattern.